# Is DispatchMessage multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I'm using a simple loop to process windows message to render a window:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)>0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

And I though I had only on e thread in my application but adding some `OutputDebugString` in the `WM_PAINT` and `WM_CHAR` portions I see that a `WM_PAINT` is called in the middle of a method I call in `WM_CHAR` which I don't see how it is possible without have several threads.

So my question is simple, does this loop use several threads to handle window messages ?

Thanks

Comment: Show your `WM_PAINT` and `WM_CHAR` handlers. Answering your question is very much dependent on them.

Comment: It is non-issue, this loop only ever dispatches messages that were delivered with PostMessage().  Which always places the message in the queue that is owned by the same thread that created the window.  You need to instead fret about SendMessage().  Which directly calls the window procedure of a window.  Only the system messages (message number less than 0x400) get automatically marshalled to the thread that owns the window.  The real problem is surely *re-entrancy*, whatever call you make gives a message loop a chance to dispatch a message.  Don't keep that real call a secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `DispatchMessage` does not use other threads to perform its work. You can check this yourself by including the thread ID in your logging output.

What you are likely observing is some re-entrant behaviour. Perhaps you called a function that in turn called `RedrawWindow`, or similar. That function in turn calls your window procedure, leading to the behaviour that you observe.

Comment: OK, it's UpdateWindow, I didn't know it did its job immediately... thanks

Comment: Yeah, doing it immediately is its MO. The docs says: *The function sends a WM_PAINT message directly to the window procedure of the specified window, bypassing the application queue.*